# Print Quotes from nested table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Trying to complete following:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE POPULATE_ACTOR_QUOTES (id_actor char)
AS
   CURSOR quote_recs IS
      SELECT m.title, 
             m.year, 
             r.roleName,
             q.quotechar 
        from quote q, 
             role r, 
             rolequote rq,  
             actor a, 
             movie m
       where rq.quoteID = q.quoteID
         AND rq.roleID = r.roleID
         AND r.actorID = a.actorID
         AND r.movieID = m.movieID
         AND a.actorID = id_actor;
BEGIN
   FOR row IN quote_recs 
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO table(
      SELECT quotes
        FROM actor_quotes aq
       WHERE aq.actorId = id_actor)
      VALUES(
         ACTOR_QUOTE_TYPE(row.title, row.year, row.roleName, row.quotechar)
      );
   end loop;
END POPULATE_ACTOR_QUOTES;
/
```

Create A PL/SQL PROCEDURE called PRINT_ACTOR_QUOTES (by modifying the procedure  POPULATE_ACTOR_QUOTES) with a single parameter that: Prints out the firstname and lastname attributes corresponding to the ACTORID (ACTORID is the procedure parameter) from the ACTOR table as well printing out all the quote information from the nested QUOTES table

This is what I have created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRINT_ACTOR_QUOTES (id_actor char)
AS
CURSOR quote_recs IS
SELECT a.firstName,a.lastName, m.title, m.year, r.roleName ,q.quotechar from quote q, role r,   
rolequote rq, actor a, movie m
where
rq.quoteID = q.quoteID
AND
rq.roleID = r.roleID
 AND
r.actorID = a.actorID
AND
r.movieID = m.movieID
AND
 a.actorID = id_actor;
BEGIN
FOR row IN quote_recs
LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( row.firstName || ' ' || row.lastName );

END LOOP;

END PRINT_ACTOR_QUOTES;
/
```

The output

```
SQL> EXECUTE PRINT_ACTOR_QUOTES ('00070')

Dustin                   Hoffman
```

need to create an output which looks like:

JEFF GOLDBLUM

```
|Title           | Year |       Role     |                Quote                               |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|THE FLY         |1986  |SETH BRUNDLE    | “I’m free and you don’t like it’’ |
|INDEPENDENCE DAY| 1996 | DAVID LEVINSON | “I’ve given it a virus”           |
```

I have the first name and second name - need the information from the the nested QUOTES table

Help needed!

I have got the following select query which brings up the needed information from the nested quotes- just need to add it to the -- PROCEDURE PRINT_ACTOR_QUOTES

```
SELECT REC.*
  FROM ACTOR_QUOTES A,TABLE(A.QUOTES) REC
  WHERE ACTORID = ('00070')
```

Comment: Your problem isn't clear, what happens when you try to loop over this query results ?

Comment: I have created an ouput with first and last name but I am having trouble adding a table under  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( row.firstName || ' ' || row.lastName ); to show the title, year, role, quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm probably missing something...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRINT_ACTOR_QUOTES (id_actor char)
AS
CURSOR quote_recs IS
SELECT a.firstName,a.lastName, m.title, m.year, r.roleName ,q.quotechar from quote q, role r,   
rolequote rq, actor a, movie m
where
rq.quoteID = q.quoteID
AND
rq.roleID = r.roleID
 AND
r.actorID = a.actorID
AND
r.movieID = m.movieID
AND
 a.actorID = id_actor;

is_first boolean := true;

BEGIN
FOR row IN quote_recs
LOOP
if is_first then
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( row.firstName || ' ' || row.lastName );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Title   | Year |    Role     |     Quote  ');
  is_first := false;
end if;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( row.title|| ' ' || row.year|| ' ' || row.role || ' ' || row.quotechar );

END LOOP;

END PRINT_ACTOR_QUOTES;
/
```